# Exception during context().headers() modification from kafka streams punctuate call

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a kafka streams application using processor API. I have a wall clock based punctuate that checks for stale entries in local statestore and deletes them and publishes messages on a kafa topic where other services are listening. Say, if there are 10 stale entries identified out of 100 entries in statestore during a punctuate call, each of the 10 entries are deleted and published over a kafka topic. The app has num.stream.threads set to 3. There are 4 input topics and each has 100 partitions - so my localstatestore also has 100 partitions. I have 2.1.1 client and 2.1+ broker (not sure of exact number). This all works fine.

Recently, one of the consuming apps for kafka messages asked to add a header that is specific to each entry that gets deleted so that they do not need to open the payload if header is not of interest to the consuming app. Since the header is specific to each entry; I am doing the following:

```
this.context().schedule(Duration.ofMinutes(EXPIRED_MINUTES), PunctuationType.WALL_CLOCK_TIME, new Punctuator() {
      @Override
      public void punctuate(long timestamp) {
        try {
          expireEntries(myStore);
        } catch (Exception e ) {
          LOG.error("Exception: ", e);
        }
      }
    });

  private void expireEntries(KeyValueStore<String, byte[]> store) {
     try (KeyValueIterator<String, byte[]> range = store.all()) {
      while (range.hasNext()) {
        KeyValue<String, byte[]> next = range.next();
        if (store.isExpired(next.key, expiredMs)) {
            addPublishEvent(next.key, next.value);
            store.delete(next.key);
        }
  }

    void addPublishEvent(String key, Message message, String topic) {

        if (message.hasInterestingProperty()) {
            for (Iterator<Header> iterator = context().headers().iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) 
            {
                Header h = iterator.next();
                if (h.key().equals("header-key")) {
                    iterator.remove();
                }
            }
            context().headers().add("header-key",  getHeaderValue(message).getBytes());
        }
        context().forward(key, message.toByteArray(), To.child(App.SINK_PREFIX + topic));

      String getHeaderValue(Message m) {
         // return m's property of interest to app;
      }
```

I get the following exceptions

1. > Exception:  java.util.ConcurrentModificationException: null\n  at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:909)\n at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:859)\n   at org.apache.kafka.common.header.internals.RecordHeaders$1.next(RecordHeaders.java:136)\n  at org.apache.kafka.common.header.internals.RecordHeaders$1.next(RecordHeaders.java:129)\n  at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorRecordContext.sizeBytes(ProcessorRecordContext.java:91)\n  at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.ContextualRecord.sizeBytes(ContextualRecord.java:42)\n  at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.LRUCacheEntry.(LRUCacheEntry.java:53)\n   at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.CachingKeyValueStore.putInternal(CachingKeyValueStore.java:243)\n   at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.CachingKeyValueStore.deleteInternal(CachingKeyValueStore.java:290)\n    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.CachingKeyValueStore.delete(CachingKeyValueStore.java:282)\n    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.CachingKeyValueStore.delete(CachingKeyValueStore.java:38)\n at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.MeteredKeyValueStore.delete(MeteredKeyValueStore.java:195)\n
2. > Exception:  java.util.ConcurrentModificationException: null\n at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:909)\n at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.remove(ArrayList.java:873)\n at org.apache.kafka.common.header.internals.RecordHeaders$1.remove(RecordHeaders.java:142)\n

So, here is the question:
Why am I getting ConcurrentModificationException? Will it stop if I have num.stream.threads as 1? I can not change threads to 1 for good; so how can I avoid hitting this exception and add header with same key but different value per message that I publish to my sink topic/ app?

Answer (score 2):

A `ConcurrentModificationException` is not related to multi-threading, but it's thrown if the underlying collection of an `Iterator` is modified. Frankly, I am not sure *why* you get the exception though, as it seems you use `iterator.remove()` what is usually ok to avoid the exception.

However, instead of iterating over the `Headers`, it would be simpler to just remove all header with the corresponding key directly via `Headers#remove()`:

```
context().headers().remove("header-key");
```

Cf: https://kafka.apache.org/21/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/common/header/Headers.html#remove-java.lang.String-

Comment: I had infact started with `context().headers().remove("header-key");`  and then I changed to the code that I pasted here in the hope that I will not hit this exception. I am not sure if you noticed, the first exception comes when I do `store.delete(next.key);`

Comment: Maybe it's related to the fact that `Headers` is not deep-copied but Kafka Streams only passed referenced between `Processor`s?

Comment: Is this something I need to take care in application (appreciate pointers on how) or needs to be fixed in library (If so, what's the workaround till it gets addressed in lib)?

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax We had hit exact same issue with processor API with 5.5. We hit the exception when we delete from a state store immediately after context.forward. This only happens in punctuate calls. This appears that in the punctuate call, the context refers to a different record while the state store delete could be a different record.

Comment: Not sure how state stores relate to headers? Also note, in a punctuation callback, `context.headers()` cannot be called, because there is no currently processed record and thus no headers. -- Maybe this is actually the missing piece to the puzzle. Just re-reading the question, it seems `context.header` is used during a punctuation... Even it `addPublishEvent` takes 3 parameter but it called with only 2? Somehow the code example from the question does not add up.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax When you invoke keyvaluestore.delete , it touches Processor Record Context residentMemorySizeEstimate method (if you notice the stack trace) which, in turn refers to the "headers" collection of the processor record context. I think this is related to the same issue as in KAFKA-9584. StampedRecord in the punctuate is based on a static DUMMY_RECORD which is being accessed from different threads to which the headers collection really belongs

Comment: Well, if you follow the discussion on the PR, it's still not valid to try to get access to headers within `punctuate()` because there are no headers because there is no record.